# Wordpress on AWS, how to update only a theme

Tags: amazon-web-services

In order to setup a flow from developer code to a public URL, I've been testing some flows and the current one does not work that good:

I have an **AWS Pipeline** that picks up the source code from **CodeCommit**, builds the **[Sage Theme](https://roots.io/sage/)** using `gulp` and deploys the entire code into an Elacticbeanstalk application.

The bad part here is that I'm pushing the entire code again and again, all I really need is the theme folder. Plus, I need to re-activate all plugins every single time :(

What is the best approach for such scenario?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not terribly familiar with elastic beanstalk, so I'm not sure if my method is at all approachable with your workflow, but I have a similar (non-AWS) workflow, and I can share how I do it.

---

I've managed to only push theme changes by separating the deployment of wordpress, and its mysql DB (both as a docker containers, in my case), and the deployment of the themes (which is a git repo).

This way I can separate/automate the deployment of wordpress, mysql, and my wordpress theme in a fairly loosely coupled manner.

Updating consists of only performing a git pull to the themes directory -- No other wordpress/mysql interaction occurs, so my plugins stay in whatever state they were previously in prior to the theme update.

Comment: please share the workflow, what are you using to upon `git push` build and deploy? an ansible playbook? can you share your directory structure and docker files ? will try on localhost and then using AWS EB.